# How to push docker images into a registry and pull them by docker-compose.yml file only

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, create-react-app

I'm new to docker, and I have some issues with the process of pushing images into a private registry and pulling them by docker-compose.yml file in another computer in our office.

I have 2 folders in my project: nginx, and client.
The nginx, is the server, and the client is create-react-app.
**nginx folder:**

default.conf:

```
upstream client {
  server client:3000;
}

server {
  listen 80;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://client;
  }

  location /sockjs-node {
    proxy_pass http://client;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
  }
}
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx
COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.confd
```

**client folder:**
nginx/default.conf:

```
server {
  listen 3000;

  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
  }
}
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine as builder

ARG REACT_APP_NODE_ENV
ENV REACT_APP_NODE_ENV $REACT_APP_NODE_ENV

WORKDIR /app
COPY ./package.json ./
RUN npm i
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx
EXPOSE 3000
COPY ./nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=builder /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Outside of the 2 folders, i have the docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    restart: always
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./nginx
    ports:
      - '3050:80'
  client:
    build:
      context: ./client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        - REACT_APP_NODE_ENV=production
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./client:/app
```

When I do inside the project folder "docker-compose up --build" everything works as I expect.

Now, I want to push the images and pull them on another computer in the office.

I first pushed the 2 images (nginx, and the client) to the registry by the following commands on the terminal:

```
docker build -t orassayag/osr_streamer_nginx:v1.0 .
 
docker tag orassayag/osr_streamer_nginx:v1.0 <office_ip_address>:5000/orassayag/osr_streamer_nginx:v1.0

docker push <office_ip_address>:5000/orassayag/osr_streamer_nginx:v1.0

docker build -t orassayag/osr_streamer_client:v1.0 .

docker tag orassayag/osr_streamer_client:v1.0 <office_ip_address>:5000/orassayag/osr_streamer_client:v1.0

docker push <office_ip_address>:5000/orassayag/osr_streamer_client:v1.0
```

Then, I updated my docker-compose.yml file as the following:

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    image: <office_ip_address>:5000/orassayag/osr_streamer_nginx
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '3050:80'
  client:
    image: <office_ip_address>:5000/orassayag/osr_streamer_client
    build:
      context: ./client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        - REACT_APP_NODE_ENV=production
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./client:/app
```

I went to other computer, created a folder name "TestDeploy", and on terminal I run "docker-compose build --pull", and I get the following error:

"ERROR: build path C:\Or\Web\StreamImages\TestDeploy\nginx either does not exist, is not accessible, or is not a valid URL."

What am I doing wrong?
I need help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the `build:` blocks in your deployment environment, or else Docker Compose will try to build the images rather than pulling them.  You also need to remove the `volumes:` there or else it will expect to find source code locally instead of in the image.

(My personal recommendation would be to remove those `volumes:` *everywhere*, do development outside of Docker, and have your Docker setup accurately reflect your deployment environment, but I seem to be in a minority on this.)